Turn off Azure Telemetry when param debug==True
Question of code quality:
Is there a better way to implement a separate debug flow/turn off opentelemetry for a FastAPI endpoint in Python rather than separating the functionality (separate function) and the logic (FastAPI endpoint)?

I am working on a FastAPI that uses the opentelemetry package to provide logging and runtime info to Azure Application Insights. The code follows the following structure for most of the endpoints:
@app.post("/some_endpont")
async def some_endpoint(request_body, username, server, debug): 
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("/some_endpoint"):
        [run some code for this endpoint]

This causes opentelemetry to also log to Application Insights when debugging locally, because there is no conditional logic around the with tracer.stract_as_current_span. I was wondering what would be an effective 'Pythonic' way to achieve that the tracer only is active when debug=False.
I came up with the following solution, which works. However this means that the API endpoint becomes more of a wrapper for the functionality, which is defined in a separate function. It doesn't look super pretty to me, so I was wondering if there is a cleaner/more Pythonic way to apply this kind of logic.
def endpoint_functionality(body, user, server, debug):
    [run some code for this endpoint]


@app.post("/some_endpont")
async def some_endpoint(request_body, username, server, debug):
    if debug == False:
        with tracer.start_as_current_span("/some_endpoint"):
            endpoint_functionality(request_body, username, server, debug)
    else:
        endpoint_functionality(request_body, username, server, debug)

